# Grep with string comparison: return only lines "higher than" a timestamp

Tags: bash, grep, zgrep

I have an email log file which records when an email went out, and who to.  This gets logrotated and so there are a mixture of zipped and unzipped log files going back a week or so.

I'm currently (successfully) getting back all lines matching a particular email with

```
sudo find /var/log/exim4/ -type f -exec zgrep -i "foobar@gmail.com" "{}" \\; | sort
```

this gives me back all emails sent to `foobar@gmail.com`.  So far so good.

What i'd like to do now is to get **all** emails sent after a specific time, regardless of recipient.  This should be simple (i think) because all of the log file lines start with a timestamp - they have this format:

```
2015-04-20 18:01:05 H=(fake.org) [180.108.175.57] F=<fake@fake.org> rejected RCPT <webmaster@charanga.com>: relay not permitted
2015-04-20 18:01:05 H=(fake.org) [180.108.175.57] F=<fake@fake.org> rejected RCPT <webmaster@charanga.com>: relay not permitted
2015-04-20 18:06:33 H=(bar.net) [111.176.77.1] F=<foo@bar.net> rejected RCPT <service@charanga.com>: relay not permitted
```

So, let's say that i want all emails sent after "2015-04-20 18:03:00".  It should just be a case of getting all lines that are "greater than" my timestamp.  How do i modify my command for this?  thanks, Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the dates are in a format where the chronological order is the same as the lexical order you can simply use `awk` like this:

```
yourcommand | awk '$0 >= "2015-04-20 18:03:00"'
```

It will output:

```
2015-04-20 18:06:33 H=(bar.net) [111.176.77.1] F=<foo@bar.net> rejected RCPT <service@charanga.com>: relay not permitted
```